# Thin film / metal film resistor

Tags: resistors

I have read various questions and posts, but still I am not sure whether when talking about resistors, thin film means the same as metal film or not.

I read the statement that "most of the metal film resistors are thin film". That means that there are also metal thick film resistors. But does it also mean, that a thin film resistor is always a metal film type?

To give an example: Are those resistors from Yageo (http://www.yageo.com/NewPortal/yageodocoutput?fileName=/pdf/R-Chip/PYu-RT_1-to-0.01_RoHS_L_9.pdf) metal film resistors?

The "resistive" layer is not specified further in the datasheet, but since the Yageo website talks about "sputtering" I assume it´s metal film?

EDIT: From the comments it seems that "thin film" and "metal film" is often used as a synonym. This seems to be the case because metal film resistors are produced by thin film techniques.
Open question seems to be therefore: What is the difference of through-hole(i.e. leaded) metal flm resistors and thin film smt resistors (beside of power and voltage rating)?
Is (in general) a leaded metal film resistor comparable to a thin film smt resistor with regard to noise? If not why not if the process (thin film) and the materials are the same?

**//Update 2020_12_31: TO close the question with the outcome from the omments/discussions. Thin-film resistor are simply one sub-category of metal-film resistors.**

Comment: Some info here https://www.vishay.com/doc?49562

Comment: More information at http://www.resistorguide.com/thin-and-thick-film/

Comment: Well, still not sure. The vishay pdf distinguishes "thin film" from "metal film" which supposes it´s not the same. The second link however says "Thin film resistors have a metallic film..."
I am not sure about the materials described in the vishay pdf (Nichrome (NiCr), Tamelox, ..) -> seems all of them are metal alloys at least.
If I get the advise to use  "metal film" resistors in a circuit because of low noise properties, are thin film resistors a proper choice?

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous because you say "metal film". The distinction is normally thick film, thin film, and metal foil, in lower of decreasing noise. Metal foil also has higher temperature stability than the other two. When you say metal film, you might actually be meaning to say metal foil. Thin film is definitely not metal foil.

Comment: I also suspect so.. Also because if I look at the vishay metal film portfolio (http://www.vishay.com/docs/49311/_metal_film_resistors_vmn_sg2030_1602.pdf), nearly all types are leaded resistors. There is one SMT family in the PDF, but package size is not comparable to the thin film SMT resistors readily available in 1206, 0805, 0603, etc....

Comment: AFAIK, tantalum nitride is a common thin film resistive material. Just because it contains a metal (tantalum) doesn't make the compound a metal any more than aluminum oxide is a metal because it contains aluminum. And a google search suggests that both tantalum nitride and ruthenium oxide (which I know is a common thick-film resistive material, but I don't know whether it's used for thin film) can be sputtered, so sputtering does not necessarily imply a metal material.

Comment: @Toor: Yes, I know that metal foil is something like a "gold standard" w.r.t noise. But here i definitely mean "metal film", and as you can se in the vishay PDF of the first comment, metal film is a subcategory of film resistors

Comment: There's an e-mail at the top of that datasheet for technical questions about their metal film products. Why don't you fire them an e-mail?

Those metal film resistors you linked have quite a bit worse temperature stability than your typical high stability thin film resistor (0.1% accuracy and 25ppm/K). Only the PSF parts at the bottom of the datasheet.

Comment: I didn't fire an email because I am quite sure that somebody around here definitely has an answer to this (rather simple?) question. I suspect many electrical engineers have to know such things in their daily life.

Comment: Simple questions aren't always so simple, especially when obfuscated by marketing. You might as well ask them. it appears to be a niche product so there's no guarantee that lots of people know about them if not a lot of people use them. The best temperature stability and tolerance numbers for these metal films match other thin films. The only difference is the rare times a noise figure is listed for thin film, it's -30dB whereas on the datasheet you linked it's -40dB.

Comment: http://www.us-tech.com/RelId/1310025/ISvars/default/Thick_Film_and_Thin_Film_Resistors_8212_Which_Is_Better_.htm
This article in the 3rd paragraph pretty much states that metal-film is just a subset of thin-film, and it seems the distinction might be moot in most cases since metal-films have become the dominant form of thin-film resistors. It would explain why your resistors marketed as metal-film have specs that match so closely to other thin-film resistors not marketed as metal-film.

Comment: This site also uses thin film as a synonym for metal film. It seems however, that they seem to talk only about through hole (i.e. leaded) resistors.
So maybe my main question now is : what is the main difference in performance between leaded metal film resistors and the thinfilm smt parts (beside of power and voltage rating)? I will edit my question

Comment: Forgot the link to the site. (see R3.3): https://passive-components.eu/resistors-non-wirewound-resistors-metal-film-foil-and-metal-oxide/

Comment: I haven't ever really assumed there was a difference between a leaded and SMT component using the same technology except for the obvious difference...the presence of leads and the associated inductances and/or capacitances, and tolerance to mechanical stress.

But the spiral coils cut into through-hole parts does contribute to parasitic inductance (and capacitance to a smaller degree) while the zig-zag etch on SMT parts contributes more to parasitic capacitance than inductance (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the discussions and reading on the net, it seems that "thin-film" resistors are simply one sub-category of "metal-film" resistors.

Answer (score -2):

If the "sea of electrons" of a metal is upset, and turned into a "sea of granules", then the electrons need to cross boundaries between the conducting granules.

This need to cross boundaries is a cause of SHOT NOISE. This shot noise is proportional to the current through the resistor (or perhaps the squareroot of the current).

You would expect carbon composition resistors to have lots of this current-dependent noise.

Now how to model the "sputtering" of tiny droplets of metal? Are the droplets in good enough contact that SHOT NOISE does not occur?

On the other hand, if the metal foil resistors use foil that is rolled out from billets of metal, we would expect few if any disruptions to the electron movement.

I've read some words about "Pauli exclusion principle" being behind these behaviors.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question at all. The OP's question re noise is through hole metal film vs SMD metal, nothing to do with foil or carbon.

Comment: This is exactly addressing the question.

Comment: In what way? To quote: "But does it also mean, that a thin film resistor is always a metal film type?" and "If not why not if the process (thin film) and the materials are the same?". There is, as I pointed out, no mention of metal *foil* or carbon resistors, so I don't see how your answer addresses the question at all.

Comment: As awjlogan mentioned: I had to edit my initial queston to set a focus und the difference between the thin film SMT resistors and the leaded resistors. I find more and more references that treat thin film SMT resistors just as a subcategory of metal film - so it would be really interesting why many people suggest to use leaded types (e.g. in audio or other equipment where noise and TCR/VCR is a topic) even in places where power rating is not a concern and SMT types should (to my knowledge) suffice.

Comment: If leaded resistors have SLOWER thermal time constants, because of a LARGE clay core inside the film resistive element, then less thermal distortion will result. On different part of the Question, I recall thick-film (THICK) can be laid down on a substrate in a silk-screen method, then BAKED to fuze the resistive particles in a conductive matrix; after baking, a laser (or a sand-blast) is used to trim the THICK FILM. These were used in hybrid circuits. (and maybe still are).